# The nth Fourier Coefficient For Poisson Kernel.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

The book says that:The function $P_{r}(\theta)$ called the Poisson Kernel, is defined for $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi] $ and $0\leq r < 1$ by the absolutely and uniformly convergent series
$$P_{r}(\theta) =\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}.$$

And it added: Note that in calculating the Fourier Coefficients of $P_{r}(\theta)$ we can interchange the order of integration and summation since the sum converges uniformly in $\theta$ for each fixed r, and obtain the Fourier coefficient equals  $ r^{|n|}$

My question is that I obtained the nth Fourier Coefficient equals $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|} $ and not  $r^{|n|}$ only, why should the summation be removed? Could anyone explain to me please?

thanks.

Comment: If $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} a_ne^{int}$ converges uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi]$ to $f,$ then $a_n$ is the $n$th Fourier coefficient of $f.$ That's a very basic and easy fact. Not sure why you think it's the whole sum above.

Comment: Is it a theorem or what? ....asI am trying to learn by myself.

Comment: Yes. Are you learning from a text? It should be in there.

Comment: yes I am learning from this book  http://bookzz.org/book/503862/2e2e8a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think that the property the book is refering to comes form the following:

$\langle P_r(\theta),e^{im\theta}\rangle=\langle \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}r^{|n|}e^{in\theta},e^{im\theta}\rangle=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}r^{|n|}\langle e^{in\theta},e^{im\theta}\rangle=$
$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}r^{|n|}\delta_{m,n}=r^{|n|}$.

This is because you can integrate each term separately , and you know that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{im\theta}\overline{e^{in\theta}}\neq0$ if and only if $m=n$.